# waves js wont initialize in a button that was created through jquery/javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I use this beautiful google inspire [waves effect](http://fian.my.id/Waves/) (called waves js). It works fine in all button but im having an issue where wave js dont work on a button that was created through jquery (refer to my snippets below). Any ideas, clues, suggestions, recommendations, help to make this work?

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
   
    Waves.attach('.waves_button');
    Waves.attach('.green_button');
    Waves.attach('.waves_button_checkbox', ['waves-circle', 'waves-float', 'waves-light']);
    Waves.init();
   $(".test").click(function(){
       $("body").append('<button class="green_button">test 2</button>');
    });
    
});
```

```css
/* green button */
.green_button{
    margin: 0 auto;
    display: block;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    font: normal 13px 'mpregular', sans-serif;
    color: #fff;
    padding: 7px 7px 3px 7px;
    width: 85px;
    color: #fff;
    border-top: none;
    border-left: none;
    border-right: none;
    border-bottom: 3px solid #659d24;
    background: #76b729;
    text-align: center;
    
    -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
    -moz-border-radius: 5px;
    border-radius: 5px;
}
.green_button:disabled{background: #d9d9d9; border: none;}
/* green button hover */
.green_button:hover{outline: none;color:#ffffff;background:#659d24 !important;border-bottom: 3px solid #659d24 !important;}
/* gray button */
.gray_button{
    margin: 0 auto;
    display: block;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    font: normal 13px 'mpregular', sans-serif;
    color: #fff;
    padding: 7px 7px 3px 7px;
    width: 85px;
    color: #fff;
    border-top: none;
    border-left: none;
    border-right: none;
    border-bottom: 3px solid #a3a1a1;
    background: #b7b7b7;
    text-align: center;
    
    -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
    -moz-border-radius: 5px;
    border-radius: 5px;
}
/* gray button when hover */
.gray_button:hover{outline: none;color:#ffffff;background:#a3a1a1 !important;border-bottom: 3px solid #a3a1a1 !important;}
/* yellowgreen button */
.yellowgreen_button{
    margin: 0 auto;
    display: block;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    font: normal 13px 'mpregular', sans-serif;
    color: #fff;
    padding: 7px 7px 3px 7px;
    width: 85px;
    color: #fff;
    border-top: none;
    border-left: none;
    border-right: none;
    border-bottom: 3px solid #b2be5b;
    background: #c6d465;
    text-align: center;
    
    -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
    -moz-border-radius: 5px;
    border-radius: 5px;
}
/* yellowgreen button when hover */
.yellowgreen_button:hover{outline: none;color:#ffffff;background:#b2be5b !important;border-bottom: 3px solid #b2be5b !important;}
/* red button */
.red_button{
    margin: 0 auto;
    display: block;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    font: normal 13px 'mpregular', sans-serif;
    color: #fff;
    padding: 7px 7px 3px 7px;
    width: 85px;
    color: #fff;
    border-top: none;
    border-left: none;
    border-right: none;
    border-bottom: 3px solid #de7171;
    background: #f17a7a;
    text-align: center;
    
    -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
    -moz-border-radius: 5px;
    border-radius: 5px;
}
/* red button when hover */
.red_button:hover{outline: none;color:#ffffff;background:#de7171 !important;border-bottom: 3px solid #de7171 !important;}
/* blue button */
.blue_button{
    margin: 0 auto;
    display: block;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    font: normal 13px 'mpregular', sans-serif;
    color: #fff;
    padding: 7px 7px 3px 7px;
    width: 85px;
    color: #fff;    
    border-top: none;
    border-left: none;
    border-right: none;
    border-bottom: 3px solid #00bceb;
    background: #00ccff;
    text-align: center;
    
    -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
    -moz-border-radius: 5px;
    border-radius: 5px;
}

/* red button when hover */
.blue_button:hover{outline: none;color:#ffffff;background:#00bceb !important;border-bottom: 3px solid #00bceb !important;}
/* all color buttons when active */
.green_button:focus, .green_button:active, .gray_button:focus, .gray_button:active, red_button:focus, red_button:active, yellowgreen_button:focus, yellowgreen_button:active, blue_button:active, blue_button:focus{outline: none;}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://fian.my.id/Waves/static/waves.min.js"></script>
<link href="http://fian.my.id/Waves/static/waves.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<button class="green_button test">test</button>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it will work if you move the attach event ( `Waves.attach('.green_button')` ) after the append if the button like this:

```
$(".test").click(function(){
  $("body").append('<button class="green_button">test 2</button>');
  Waves.attach('.green_button');
});
```

I tested it and it work well.

Answer (score 1):

This library doesn't work this way...
It doesn't "attach" to an active selector list, it attaches to the static list matching the selectors at the time the `attach` function is called.

You can remedy this simply by attaching each new button as well:

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
   
    Waves.attach('.waves_button');
    Waves.attach('.green_button');
    Waves.attach('.waves_button_checkbox', ['waves-circle', 'waves-float', 'waves-light']);
    Waves.init();
   $(".test").click(function(){
       var newButton = $('<button class="green_button">test 2</button>');
       $("body").append(newButton);
       Waves.attach(newButton.get(0));
    });
    
});
```

```css
/* green button */
.green_button{
    margin: 0 auto;
    display: block;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    font: normal 13px 'mpregular', sans-serif;
    color: #fff;
    padding: 7px 7px 3px 7px;
    width: 85px;
    color: #fff;
    border-top: none;
    border-left: none;
    border-right: none;
    border-bottom: 3px solid #659d24;
    background: #76b729;
    text-align: center;
    
    -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
    -moz-border-radius: 5px;
    border-radius: 5px;
}
.green_button:disabled{background: #d9d9d9; border: none;}
/* green button hover */
.green_button:hover{outline: none;color:#ffffff;background:#659d24 !important;border-bottom: 3px solid #659d24 !important;}
/* gray button */
.gray_button{
    margin: 0 auto;
    display: block;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    font: normal 13px 'mpregular', sans-serif;
    color: #fff;
    padding: 7px 7px 3px 7px;
    width: 85px;
    color: #fff;
    border-top: none;
    border-left: none;
    border-right: none;
    border-bottom: 3px solid #a3a1a1;
    background: #b7b7b7;
    text-align: center;
    
    -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
    -moz-border-radius: 5px;
    border-radius: 5px;
}
/* gray button when hover */
.gray_button:hover{outline: none;color:#ffffff;background:#a3a1a1 !important;border-bottom: 3px solid #a3a1a1 !important;}
/* yellowgreen button */
.yellowgreen_button{
    margin: 0 auto;
    display: block;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    font: normal 13px 'mpregular', sans-serif;
    color: #fff;
    padding: 7px 7px 3px 7px;
    width: 85px;
    color: #fff;
    border-top: none;
    border-left: none;
    border-right: none;
    border-bottom: 3px solid #b2be5b;
    background: #c6d465;
    text-align: center;
    
    -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
    -moz-border-radius: 5px;
    border-radius: 5px;
}
/* yellowgreen button when hover */
.yellowgreen_button:hover{outline: none;color:#ffffff;background:#b2be5b !important;border-bottom: 3px solid #b2be5b !important;}
/* red button */
.red_button{
    margin: 0 auto;
    display: block;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    font: normal 13px 'mpregular', sans-serif;
    color: #fff;
    padding: 7px 7px 3px 7px;
    width: 85px;
    color: #fff;
    border-top: none;
    border-left: none;
    border-right: none;
    border-bottom: 3px solid #de7171;
    background: #f17a7a;
    text-align: center;
    
    -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
    -moz-border-radius: 5px;
    border-radius: 5px;
}
/* red button when hover */
.red_button:hover{outline: none;color:#ffffff;background:#de7171 !important;border-bottom: 3px solid #de7171 !important;}
/* blue button */
.blue_button{
    margin: 0 auto;
    display: block;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    font: normal 13px 'mpregular', sans-serif;
    color: #fff;
    padding: 7px 7px 3px 7px;
    width: 85px;
    color: #fff;    
    border-top: none;
    border-left: none;
    border-right: none;
    border-bottom: 3px solid #00bceb;
    background: #00ccff;
    text-align: center;
    
    -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
    -moz-border-radius: 5px;
    border-radius: 5px;
}

/* red button when hover */
.blue_button:hover{outline: none;color:#ffffff;background:#00bceb !important;border-bottom: 3px solid #00bceb !important;}
/* all color buttons when active */
.green_button:focus, .green_button:active, .gray_button:focus, .gray_button:active, red_button:focus, red_button:active, yellowgreen_button:focus, yellowgreen_button:active, blue_button:active, blue_button:focus{outline: none;}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://fian.my.id/Waves/static/waves.min.js"></script>
<link href="http://fian.my.id/Waves/static/waves.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<button class="green_button test">test</button>
```